# C# Generic Parameter used in Base Class method call is Base Class - Not Derived :(

Tags: generics, inheritance, c#-4.0

I'm feeling a little deflated as I've forgotten something that is probably really fundamental in .NET and generics. Just wondering if there is a way to fix this.  Project is C# .NET 4.0.

I have a base entity class **BaseEntity** for which I am trying to abstract validation.

```
public abstract class BaseEntity : IEntity
{
    public bool IsValid
    {
        get
        {
            Validator.Validate(this);
            return validationResults.Count == 0;
        }
    }
        .
        .
}
```

The Validator class uses a [*Static Gateway*](http://blog.jpboodhoo.com/TheStaticGatewayPattern.aspx) to initialize with a concrete IValidatorFactory.  A provided concrete factory implementation is responsible for creating an IValidator that actual carries out the validation.

```
public class Validator
{
    private static IValidatorFactory factory;

    public static void Initialize(IValidatorFactory validationFactory)
    {
        factory = validationFactory;
    }

    public static void Validate<TEntity>(TEntity entity) where TEntity : IEntity
    {
        if (factory == null) return null;
        var validator = factory.GetValidator<TEntity>();
        if (validator == null) return;
        entity.ClearValidationResults();
        validator.Validate(entity); //Adds validation results to the entity's validation result collection
    }
}
```

My problem is that when

```
factory.GetValidatory<TEntity>()
```

is called in the *Validator* class, *TEntity* is type **BaseEntity** instead of the **derived** entity I need it to be.  As a result, the factory tries to return a

```
IValidator<BaseEntity>
```

instead of

```
IValidator<DerivedEntity>.
```

This is probably because **Validator.Validate(this)** is being called in the *BaseEntity* class so is actually

```
Validator.Validate<BaseEntity>(this)
```

when what I want is

```
Validator.Validate<MyDerivedEntity>(this)
```

Is there anyway to make Validator.Validate<>() use the derived type instead of BaseEntity?

*Note that BaseEntity doesn't "know" about the derived types at compile time.*

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use generics in the factory:

```
var validator = factory.GetValidator(entity.GetType());
```

(Or you may of course decide to move that elsewhere, but the principle remains: call `GetType()` rather than using `typeof(TGeneric)`),

Comment: The factory still needs to return IValidator<TEntity> so I'm unsure how that would work as this isn't allowed: IValidator<TEntity> GetValidator(Type entityType);

Comment: This answer provides a reasonable approach but it doesn't provide a solution to my problem.  I'll have to revisit how I'm doing things.